# How to install 18.04 on a desktop computer with Nvidia GPU?

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, system-installation, intel, gigabyte

so I am trying to install 18.04 on my desktop with Nvidia graphic cards and i9-9900k. Motherboard Auros z390 master. Now the installation won’t boot from my usb, which might be due to lack of Nvidia driver? So what should I do? Take out the Nvidia gpu and install it or anything better to do?

ps I don’t think it’s possible to boot from intel graphic card — when you have Nvidia GPU plugged in?

**Update: problem solved after I took Nvidia gpu off and install 18.04, then install nvidia drivers and put gpu back**

Comment: Which Ubuntu 18.04 did you try and install?  The original 2018-April release?  second release or 18.04.1?, or third 18.04.2? with HWE enabled and using the 18.10 software stack?, 18.04.3? with HWE & 19.04's software stack? or ....   I've assumed desktop but clarification of specifics may help us to better help you.

Comment: @guiverc 18.04.3 downloaded from ubuntu website, then made into a bootable disk. Idk how to get it with HWE and 19.04’s software stack...

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.3 has HWE enabled by default (18.04.2 & later do), and the .3 uses the 19.04 [HWE] software stack; 18.04.4 uses 19.10's etc.  The detail 18.04.3 tells us.  Assuming you verified your ISO (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and write to install media (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck where CD is cd/dvd/hdd/ssd/thumb-drive/.. if not I'd do them!!) and assuming you tried with *safe graphics* trying 18.04.4 would be my next step as it's super easy to do.  Check your install media

Comment: @guiverc some said 19.10 solved some issues with intel integrated gpu of 9900k, so this is interesting... but it kinda sucks that I have to wait till February 8th to try it...

Comment: Feb 8th?   (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule shows feb 6th, but you can try it now - http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/384/builds; I didn't provide link to the direct daily as it'll be different in hours when a new 'daily' gets created)

Comment: @guiverc thanks I’ll try it